# How do I get $JAVA_HOME by Jsch

Tags: java, jsch

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))
echo JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))
echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar xxxxx
```

I want to execute this script on a remote machine in jsch:

```
public boolean actionShell(Session sshSession, String command) {
        boolean flag = false;
        Channel channel = null;
            try {
            channel = sshSession.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();

            while (true) {
                 if (channel.isClosed()) {
                     if (in.available() > 0) continue;
                         flag = channel.getExitStatus() == 0 ? true : false;
                         log.info("exit-status: " + flag);
                         break;
                     }
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("error", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (channel != null || channel.isConnected())
                    channel.disconnect();
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

The results show that this sh script can not get JAVA_HOME's value.

```
JAVA_HOME=
JAVA_HOME=
/bin/java -jar xxxxx
```

Because of we don't get conf of remote matchine, we can not point out the JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Do you get different results, when you execute the script in an interactive SSH terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get a non-interactive and non-login shell and insert this code in script:

`#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile
. ~/.profile`

non-interactive and non-login shell will not to to find and loading "BASH_ENV". there is a image show differences of file loading.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jREZ.png)

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or additional information to your question?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Hi Martin Prikryl, That is my solutions. may be useful for some people.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should set the JAVA_HOME variable on your OS. Have you tried?

Comment: This should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

If the remote machine is not setting $JAVA_HOME in the environment of the remote, then (obviously) it will be empty when you get it.

So either, you need to:

- change the remote machine's remote shell initialization to set an appropriate $JAVA_HOME, or
- pass an appropriate $JAVA_HOME setting in the script you are running, or
- write a clever shell function that can "intuit" an appropriate $JAVA_HOME setting; e.g. by looking in the various places where a JRE *could have been* installed.

Comment: Thank yon Stephen C. As you said, we have set $JAVA_HOME at path of /etc/profile. In my question the ssh login mode is the cause of the problem. we can find some info from this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells)

Comment: “When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-interactive shell with the –login option, it first attempts to read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that order. The –noprofile option may be used to inhibit this behavior. When invoked as an interactive shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is defined, ... ” —Learning the bash Shell, 2nd Edition

Answer (score 0):

Jsch’s session environment doesn't have the /etc/profile configuration... You can execute [ `source /etc/profile;` ] before to load the configuration. And then, you can execute any apps successful....